# How to scrape an income statement from Yahoo Finance into google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape an income statement for Apple (AAPL) into google sheets
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL

First off I'd like to say I'm new to using anything technical or function related for computers so sorry if its a dumb question but I'm aware sheets has built in import functions for web data and I tried using the IMPORTXML function and I couldn't find the right xpath for the whole income statement

So my questions are

1. Which Import function would be best for scraping the income statement into sheets
2. Whichever function is the best how can I do it.
3. Would I repeat the steps that you show me if I wanted to scrape the balance sheet and cash flow as well

- Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to fetch dynamically generated data in the link you've provided. Import functions cannot be used or cannot function properly in **dynamically generated data** as well as in websites which data are being controlled by **JavaScript**.

I suggest finding another link or website that will provide you with the same data and can be fetched through IMPORT functions by taking into consideration the mentioned limitations above.

Comment: Okay thank you! Can you fetch dynamically generated data by writing a script?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. But I think it should be possible. For example, you can use python for web scraping and use google sheets api to put the fetched data in your sheet. In theory, this should work. :)

Comment: @ZacharyKocjancic If I answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer